# cursor.moveToFirst() always return false

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have searched here for a while and nothing helped me. I guess it is simple, I'm doing something stupid. So, I have this DataBaseHelper do create a table and put two values on it:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    public static final String PROPERTY = "property";
    public static final String VALUE = "value";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE configs (property VARCHAR(15), value VARCHAR(10));");
    
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        
        cv.put(PROPERTY, "registered");
        cv.put(VALUE, "true");
        db.insert("configs", PROPERTY, cv);
        
        cv.put(PROPERTY, "test");
        cv.put(VALUE, "test");
        db.insert("configs", PROPERTY, cv);
    }
}
```

and in my activity im trying:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutRegister);
    
    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM configs", 
            null);
    
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        debug = new TextView(this);
        debug.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("property")));
        layout.addView(debug);
    }
}
```

and it never enters in the if. Moreover, when I try something like     cursor.getCount() I get a *android.content.res.Resource$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0*

I guess it is a simple mistake, but... Any help?

Comment: I think you are missing many things. As for example, class for CRUD operations, too. Refer to this link, Its a good example as a start. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ , http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thanks, Im aware of it. But it is just a little test/learning... For such a simple test I dont need that (do I?). I will read it of course, maybe it enlight me.

Answer (score 6):

What I understood you want to set the Text when cursor having values so you can simply do this...

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM configs", null);

    if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        debug = new TextView(this);
        debug.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("property")));
        layout.addView(debug);
    }
```

And about

```
when I try something like cursor.getCount() I get a android.content.res.Resource$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

It is because when you using [**setText()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) of TextView, So if you passing parameter as Integer then it will look in R.class file so if you want to set text as integer you can do something like...

```
debug.setText(""+cursor.getCount());
```

or

```
 debug.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
```

Comment: The part of the Exception work, thanks. But the cursor.getCount() is returning 0. So he is saying that is no data from the query and the if (cursor.moveToFirst()) will return false... Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to query use **getReadableDatabase** not **getWritableDatabase**

and always **`cursor.close();`**

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
cv.put(property, "registered");
cv.put(value, "true");
```

and

```
cv.put(property, "test");
cv.put(value, "test");
```

instead of

```
cv.put(PROPERTY, "registered");
cv.put(VALUE, "true");
```

and

```
cv.put(PROPERTY, "test");
cv.put(VALUE, "test");
```